# codeigniter select result array format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select, activerecord

I have this code:

```
 $query = $this->db->select( 'cat_id' )
            ->from( 'products_cat' )
            ->where('product_id',$id)
            ->get()
            **->result_array();**
return $query;
```

It's return value in this format:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [cat_id] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [cat_id] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [cat_id] => 5 ) )
```

And I want it to return simple array like `Array(2,3,5)`

(Without arrays inside arrays and without the "cat_id" index)

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2):

replace your `return $query;`
with this
`return array_map( function( $data ) { return $data['cat_id']; }, $query );`

Comment: It work. thank you. but is it really the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

result_array() returns a json_decoded array. Use `json_encode($query)`